# dice notation in excel

Tags: excel, dice

i'm having an issue in excel and i need help from someone who knows better.

Quick story : i'm a rolist, i'm doing character sheet on excel and i need to do `dice notation` calcul.

I need to be able to write in a cell something like `3d6+2d4+6` or `3d8+2+3d9-2d6` or any combinaison. and then calculate the result in a other cell.

something like `Rolldice(A1)` and it would calculate it (if `3d8+2+4d8` was given it would give a number between `9` and `58`)

Basicaly `1d6` means `1` dice with six faces, thus a random number betwen `1` and `6`. `2d6` would mean doing `1d6 + 1d6` (thus a number between `2` and `12`)

I don't mind if the result requires me to set the dices between braquets as in : `(3d6)+2+(4d8)`

it should be able to add, substract or multiply dices

`1dX + 1dX or 1dX - 1dX or 1dX * 1dX`

I would be immensly thankfull to the one who manage to do that.

I hope i made myself clear enough. feel free to ask specifications if needed.

Best regards,

ps: thanks for fixing my lack of good english. it's especially great to see the reviews and learn from it !

Comment: i'm trying with conditionnal formating. i'm no coder, that why i ask :) is it forbiden?

Comment: Do you have any interest in a **VBA** solution??

Comment: can add it through a alt +f11 then insert module right?

I don't mind how it's done. as long as i can use it in excel 2007 and that it is easily inserted (or well explained on how to put it into excel, i'm good at following instructions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have dice expressions in column **A**

Hi-light the cells and run this small macro:

```
Sub DiceXlator()
    Dim r As Range, v As String, NewForm As String, deemode As Boolean
    Dim dee As String
    dee = "d"
    deemode = False
    For Each r In Selection
        v = r.Value
        NewForm = "="
        For i = 1 To Len(v)
            ch = Mid(v, i, 1)
            If ch = dee Then
                NewForm = NewForm & "*RANDBETWEEN(1,"
                deemode = True
            Else
                If Not IsNumeric(ch) And deemode Then
                    deemode = False
                    NewForm = NewForm & ")"
                End If
                NewForm = NewForm & ch
            End If
        Next i

        If deemode Then
            NewForm = NewForm & ")"
        End If

        r.Offset(0, 1).Formula = NewForm
    Next r
End Sub
```

The macro translates each dice expression into a standard Excel formula and places the formula in the adjacent cell in column **B**

Here is a tiny example of *inputs/outputs*

[image: sample]

**EDIT#1:**

Here is the same logic in the form of a *User Defined Function* - **UDF**

```
Public Function RollDice(r As Range) As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    Dim v As String, NewForm As String, deemode As Boolean
    Dim dee As String
    dee = "d"
    deemode = False
        v = r.Value
        NewForm = "="
        For i = 1 To Len(v)
            ch = Mid(v, i, 1)
            If ch = dee Then
                NewForm = NewForm & "*RANDBETWEEN(1,"
                deemode = True
            Else
                If Not IsNumeric(ch) And deemode Then
                    deemode = False
                    NewForm = NewForm & ")"
                End If
                NewForm = NewForm & ch
            End If
        Next i

        If deemode Then
            NewForm = NewForm & ")"
        End If

        RollDice = Evaluate(NewForm)

End Function
```

**EDIT#2:**

It is possible to get *Min, Max,* and *Average* in a statistical sense.  For example in **B1** enter:

```
=RollDice($A$1)
```

then copy **B2** from **B3** thru **B1000**

and finally use:

```
=MAX(B1:B1000)
=MIN(B1:B1000)
=AVERAGE(B1:B1000)
```

Comment: i just re read. actually i think it can do the trick. i'll give it a try.

Comment: **Yes** ............the macro can be changed to *replace* the dice expressions if that is your requirement.....or the **sub** can be changed into a **function** that just returns the numerical value.

Comment: It does the trick. Thanks a lot !

can i have the same macro but who express the minimum value, maximum value and average value ?

Comment: That would be a MUCH, MUCH more difficult task!

Comment: that i understand. I also found an issue with the macro.

It make the value "hard coded". if i change the expresion for the damage, i have to rerun the macro.

as for what i ask, all it have to do is

If expression is 1d6
then do
 1x1
 1x6
 1x(6/2)

basically.

I would rather have function RollDice(A1) where the result is changing if the expression in A1 change (without having to run a macro)

Comment: that's awesome !

i'll be digging into it to transform it. with those two i shoul dhave enough content to work on.

Kudos !

Comment: is it possible to have a RollMin(cell) that you give the minimum, RollMax(cell) that would give the maximum and RollAv(cell) that would give the average ?

Comment: it works but it take too much space. it will end up in a character sheet and will be then printed...

Comment: Hide extraneous rows before printing.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the functions RAND and RANDBETWEEN

Setup a table listing the dice choices 1 roll , 2 rolls etc and use those functions to calculate values from the inputs.

Keep the inputs separate from the table of calculations. Separate input from calculations and Separate output. You can even use different sheets in a workbook.

Don't worry about the notation at first, get the functions working.

Then you can format the output using string CONCATENATE to build up your notation.

Conditional formatting is only used once you have differing values in the excel cells and is probably not applicable here.

Comment: I'm used to the RAND and especially RADNBETWEEN.

That's the way i roll dice for now.

Given cell A1, A2, A3 and A4
A1 is the number of dices : =1
A2 display "d" for visual convenience
A3 display the dice type : =6
A4 is : randbetween(1,A3)

I would like to have it differently.

A1 : would be 1d6+6
A2 would be a result between 7 and 12 (with a function like Rolldice(1d6+6)

I would rather avoid having to fill secondary spreadsheep. I would like to create a function that i could use at will, like a RAND but allowing me to calculte using dice notation

Comment: i just tryed concatenate...

*Jaw dropping*

i've got so much to learn !

Comment: other really useful things are INDEX,LOOKUP and MATCH (lookup up and ref section), at first I had to play around with these to get use to them but worth time investment. Absolute and relative cell addressing is also a must if you haven't come accross. Excel has so much power there very rarely need to do VBA