# Dice notation in excel, advanced mode

Tags: excel, notation, dice

I'm back on the same topic (dice roll in dice notation in excel) with a specific questions.

I asked if someone could make me a "User Defined Function" for excell that you calculate an equation expressed in dice notation (for rpg. like 1d6+3)

Here's the result (and it work really well)
[dice notation in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253155/dice-notation-in-excel)

Now, i need three more functions.

1) RollMax(A1) that would give the max value of A1 (if A1 = 1d6+3, the result would be 9)

2) RollMin(A1) that would give the min value of A1 (if A1 = 1d6+3, the result would be 4)

3) RollAve(A1) that would give the average value of A1 (if A1 = 1d6+3, the result would be 6)

I need it in the same way as the Rolldice() made by Gary's in the linked post. It will be used by players that know nbothing in excel and i want it as seemless as possible.

Thanks a lot

best regards

Comment: I wonder if this would get more success on SuperUser? While it's definitely a programming question they may know more about the Office software...

Comment: superuser? (i know what a superuser is, i think you refer to an otherpart of stack overflow. right?)

Comment: sorry the SuperUser site - http://superuser.com see if anyone can help you here first though!